# Javascript cookies not being deleted under circumstances

Tags: javascript

I want to delete a cookie and I achieve it using this code:

```
document.cookie = 'cookie=1;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

So, let's say I am in the page domain.com/new . When I execute this function, the cookie gets deleted. If I see this page under domain.com/new/ , the cookie doesn't go away. What is going on?

Comment: When you set the cookie do you set a path

Comment: No, I just do document.cookie = 'fb=1; ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I add the cookie with this code

```
    document.cookie = 'fb=1;path=/';
```

and delete it with this code

```
 document.cookie = 'fb=1;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;path=/';
```